# Sample WPF apps for line of business apps?

Tags: wpf, design-patterns

I am learning WPF and wanted to look at source code to some good full fledged WPF apps which are used for business apps, data binding using data bound controls like grids and good use of WPF design and patterns.

Not interested in WPF apps which show off WPF's graphics capabilities. Yes I am into your typical boring business apps. Also looking further than codeproject.com. If you know something good at CodePlex, a pointer would be helpful.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeProject.com is a very good resource for finding examples of .NET applications.  Some articles are at a "here's a control, here are some example usages", but there are the occasional full-fledged app write-ups too.

Here are a couple of examples of some business-y WPF usage which may fill your needs:

- [WPF Business Application Series Part
  1 of n By Karl Shifflett](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFBusinessAppsPartOne.aspx)
- [WPF DataGrid Practical Examples By
  Colin Eberhardt](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx)
- [Binding and using Friendly enums in
  WPF By Sacha Barber](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/FriendlyEnums.aspx)

You can find many more in the WPF section.

Comment: Pardon me - I can't post links because I'm a new user.  Here they are:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/FriendlyEnums.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/

Answer (score 2):

The Patterns and Practices group at Microsoft has published a Composite Application "guidance" that is code-named Prism.  It includes a demo stock-trading app and source code with examples of various design patterns.  It's [here on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF).